# JQuery AJAX Refresh Multiple Divs (Repeating Refresh)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've spent a couple hours looking on here for an answer but I couldn't find one. My auto-refresh works, the problem is it refreshes all of the divs inside of each other. For example, I have a computer aided dispatch application that has a seciton for available units, assigned calls, and pending calls, but when it refreshes, it puts ALL three of these divs into all three of each other!

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    $('#avunits').load('supervisor.php #avrefresh');
}, 5000);
```

The other problem is I've tried to just do them with the multiple div syntax but that only works on the first div and ignores the other two:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    $('#avunits,#assigned,#pending').load('supervisor.php .refresh');
}, 5000);
```

In the second example, it puts all three divs into the Available Units div but doesn't update the assigned or pending.

Last, I've tried doing all three together in the same one and it still didn't work:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    $('#avunits').load('supervisor.php #avrefresh', function (){
        $('#assigned').load('supervisor.php #avrefresh', function (){
            $('#pending').load('supervisor.php #penrefresh');
})})}, 5000);
```

What I want it to do, is refresh all three divs and keep them separate.

The relevant code:

```
    // All of the code is within the same webpage. I plan to separate them to their own pages once everything works.
// This is the working version. Currently, the AVRefresh works, but if I do what I said in my Stack Overflow post, it doesn't work.

<head>
    <?if($_GET['info'])
    {   }
    else
    {?>
        <script src="java/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function () {
             // If I use "#avunits" after supervisor.php it embedds a second DIV. So, I made a new one so as to not mess up my CSS
            $('#avunits').load('supervisor.php #avrefresh');
            }, 5000);
        </script>
    <?}?>       
    <title>WebCAD Dispatch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="supervisor_base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="callview_assigned.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="callview_pending.css">
</head>
<body>



// (Continued)


<div id="background">
    <div id="fixedwidth">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="avunits">
                <div id="avrefresh">
                        // Various MySQL Queries
                        // If the user is a supervisor, staff, or admin, and is not banned and approved.
                        {
                            if(isset($_GET['info']) || isset($_GET['refresh']))
                            {
                                // Various MySQL Queries                                    
                                // HTML/PHP Readouts/Echoes

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Various MySQL / PHP / HTML Codes that retrieve the users
                                // And prints out all units, and if busy, their status and Call#
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Javascript back to index.php for login prompt
                        }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="callview">
                <div id="assigned">
                    <div id="assigned_refresh">
                        // Various MYSQL/PHP Calls to retrieve incident information and assigned units (if any)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="pending">
                    <div id="pending_refresh">
                        // Various MYSQL/PHP Calls to retrieve incident information
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

// (Continued)

</body>
```

I removed the irrelevant MySQL/PHP Code to protect the applications integrity.

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: `.load` like `.html`/`.text` and other setter methods it only operates on the first matched element, that is why it only inserts into `#avunits`. As for the last snippet what about it didn't work? Did it not load the element fetched from supervisor.php into the specified element? Did it add everything from supervisor.php to the element? If you want to only fetch supervisor.php once per interval but separate parts of it to separate elements you probably want to a `$.get` and separate the data within the callback instead of trying to use `.load`

Comment: The third section of code, it caused #avunits to reload but not the other two. It didn't cause them to dupe or anything, just didn't reload the other two (assigned/pending)

Comment: Are you saying to separate the loaded portion into it's own .php, and use get to call them individually? AKA not part of the page's code but called into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to load one page, and then replace different fragments of your page with different fragments of the loaded page.  You're not going to be able to accomplish that with load(), unless you want to load the same page three different times.  Instead, you'll need to use $.get() and update the fragments yourself:

```
$.get("refresh.php")
    .done(function(r) {
        var newDom = $(r);
        $('#avunits').replaceWith($('#avunits',newDom));
        $('#assigned').replaceWith($('#assigned',newDom));
        $('#pending').replaceWith($('#pending',newDom));
     });
```

If you absolutely must use load, you'll need to handle each fragment separately and explicitly.  As mentioned in the Xorifelse's answer, unlike many jQuery methods, get() runs for the first matched element, and ignores the rest.  So if you use $(".refresh").get() only the first element of class "refresh" will be updated.

```
$('#avunits').load('supervisor.php #avunits_refresh');
$('#assigned').load('supervisor.php #assigned_refresh');
$('#pending').load('supervisor.php #pending_refresh');
```

Comment: I'll look into that right now and get back to you. Thank you for the thorough explanation. I just broke into JQuery so my inexperience is what caused this issue. In fact, yes, the info is all on one page. I will get back to you.

Comment: I can't get that to work. When I put it in, it does nothing, even when I try to change around the names. I probably just don't have the knowledge. When I use that, it never updates or changes.

Comment: @MichaelHarris, Can you post the HTML for the page you're updating and for refresh.php, if that's a different page?

Comment: @MichaelHarris, can't access pastebin from my current location.  I'll try to take a look at it this evening.  I suspect an issue with the selectors, though.

Comment: Added it above. Edited into the main post.

Comment: Okay.  My code should work.  At this point it's probably time to examine the developer console, and see if there are any errors being thrown, and also to verify that the page is being properly pulled.  The Chrome console is the easiest to work with:  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en

Comment: @MichaelHarris - I know you omitted some code, but you also mention that you are new to jQ. Your PHP code seems to want some parameters sent to it, none of the examples are satisfying those `isset($_GET['refresh']` statements.

Comment: The MySQL/PHP all works flawlessly, that segment is just to avoid displaying the available units if the refresh is set to false, which was my old method of refreshing (html meta refresh). It's going to be removed after this works.

Comment: I opened the console but there's nothing there. When I typed in the var auto_refresh, it just printed 1. When I used your code, it came back with a large list of everything that seems to check out just fine. Here's a screenshot of it. http://puu.sh/nkddl/5658343b48.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by using `'supervisor.php .refresh'`, `$('#.refresh')`, the if then else clause from `supervisor.php #avrefresh`, or the most strange one `$('#avunits,#assigned,#pending').load('supervisor.php .refresh');
}, 5000);`

it does exactly what you say it does. Change the HTML code *in* these divs `#avunits,#assigned,#pending` to the output of `load('supervisor.php .refresh')`

However I'm not even sure if jQuery excepts this as a valid input and would presumably pick the first element found and skip the rest and for the load function I would not venture a guess on where you got that documentation from. As by comment below, it expects at most a html ID and not a class and ignores the rest (even your selector) stated in the documentation.

---

`load()` expects a valid URL. if you want to do different things with `supervisor.php` you should use a valid URL by doing `load('supervisor.php?action=assigned')` and sepperate them with an if/else clause in your PHP script by doing a `if($_GET['action'] == 'assigned'){} elseif($_GET['action'] == 'pending'){} else {//code for malicous data}` and so on to return a different output.

The else statement in this example, should be an action if the user sends malicious data to the ajax request.

### Warning

If you do not change the `load()` url there will be a chance that jQuery or even the browser caches the response. You would need to clear the cache or use links with `$_GET` requests to separate the caching.

Comment: "supervisor.php .refresh" is a valid url argument for load().  See "loading page fragments" under the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: In all examples, I see an css ID not a css class. And HTML id's are expected to be *unique* where again, jQuery just picks the first id found. And if you use an ID in the load parementer the rest is discarted as explained in the documentary.

Comment: I used ".refresh" because when I was specifying the ID of the assigned/pending, it was reinserting it twice unless I put a new div inside of the div being reloaded. Now I understand why. I wasn't refreshing, I was loading into it. Inexperience.